# printk message doesn't display till next event

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dmesg

[image: Reference Image]

I am a beginner to kernel module programming so this might turn out to be something dumb.

I am following [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x351.html). I am trying to make a module that spans multiple files. (from the guide).

The individual files are:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world - this is the kernel speaking");
    return 0;
}
```

and,

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

void cleanup_module()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Short is the life of a kernel module");
}
```

Here's my makefile.

```
obj-m += hello-1.o
obj-m += startstop.o
startstop-objs := start.o stop.o 

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

(`hello-1` is from a previous exercise)

The module compiles successfully. The image at the top shows the complete output of `make`. After compiling, I insert the module `[Jan21 07:25]` and then remove it `[ +10.624728]`. Then I connect a USB Mouse just to prove the point. I am running `$ dmesg -wH` on the right hand side terminal window.

The output is as expected but at different times.

1. The `hello world ...` output gets displayed when I remove the module `at +10.624...`.
2. The `Short is the life ...` output gets displayed when I insert the USB mouse.
3. The `new device` message however is displayed right on time.

---

My initial guess was that there is probably some buffering mechanism at play here so I tried raising the priority on the `printk()` all the way to `KERN_ALERT` but to no effect. Also why is the message getting flushed from the buffer when the mouse is getting connected? And why is the mouse output not buffered? I really could move ahead with this much but I would like to know what is happening under hood.

PS: Please ignore the weird usernames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel ring buffer is line buffered, which means it's not flushed until it encounters a newline. Add a `\n` to the end of your `printk` strings:

```c
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world - this is the kernel speaking\n");
```

You also might consider using the printk formatting macros, as I believe these are preferred over specifying `KERN_INFO` directly:

```c
pr_info("Hello, world - this is the kernel speaking\n");
```

If you want to put two separate kernel messages on the same line, you would use:

```c
pr_info("Hello, world - ");
pr_cont("this is the kernel speaking\n");
```

which has the same effect as the original line.